# Standard ML : trying to get the right signature of a function

Tags: sml, ml

Im trying to make a function with this signature :

```
'a->'b->('a * 'b ->'b)->'b
```

I have tried to do a function like this :

```
fun f x y z = z(x,y);
```

but its signature is different , it is :

```
'a->'b->('a * 'b ->'c)->'c
```

How can i make it fit with the requested?
Any tip maybe?

Comment: Your question looks good. I would only suggest that you add some links to research you have done into this question, so that it seems you have already put work into figuring this out before asking others to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the least "artificial" would be something like:

```
fun f x y g = g (x, g (x, y))
```

which ensures that g's return-type matches the type of its second parameter by calling g twice, with the result of one call being the second argument to the other.

But a simpler solution, if this isn't "cheating", is to just add an explicit type annotation:

```
fun f x (y : 'b) g : 'b = g (x, y)
```